# Jquery (Window).Resize() calling function incorrectly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

basically I have a function that resizes elements accordingly with jquery triggering the function on end of the resizing of the window.

it works perfectly apart from when I resize the window back to original size, I do not see the  same thing as if I refresh the page. Which is weird considering the exact same function is being called.

The problem can be seen live **[here](http://thepelican.me/test/browse.html)**

The Js:

```
var waitForFinalEvent = (function () {
var timers = {};
return function (callback, ms, uniqueId) {
if (!uniqueId) {
  uniqueId = "Don't call this twice without a uniqueId";
}
if (timers[uniqueId]) {
  clearTimeout (timers[uniqueId]);
}
timers[uniqueId] = setTimeout(callback, ms);
};
})();




$(window).resize(function () {
waitForFinalEvent(function(){

loadcontext();

  //...
}, 10, "some unique string");
});



function loadcontext() {

var winwidth = window.innerWidth;
var winheight = window.innerHeight;

<!-- Fixes layout on screens -->    

if (winwidth < 1200)
{   
$('#blockscontainer').css("left", (winwidth / 2)*-1 );
$('.block').css("width", (winwidth - 30)/ 5 );  
$('.block').css("height", (winwidth - 30)/ 7.5 );
$('#blockscontainer').css("width", winwidth -20);
}
else
{
$('#blockscontainer').css("left", (1200 / 2)*-1 );
$('.block').css("width", 1173 / 5 );
}   

};
```

The CSS:

```
body { margin: 0px; padding: 0px;  }
#contentcontain {clear: both; left: 50%; }
#blockscontainer {clear: both; height: 100%; max-width: 1180px; width: 100%; background-         color: #EEE; padding: 10px; border-radius: 15px;}
#blockcontext {overflow: auto;width: 100% clear: both; position: relative; height: 100%;    background-color: #DDD;border-radius: 7px; padding-bottom: 20px;}
#footer { width: 100%; margin-top: 30px; text-align: center; background-color: #666; }
#content {  background-color: #333;  padding-top: 50px;}
.block {display: inline-block;  height: 150px; width: 200px; background-color: #FFF; float: left; margin-top: 20px; border: 1px solid #CCC;}
```

The HTML:

```
<body onload="loadcontext()">
<div id="content">
<div id="contentcontain" align="center">
<div id="blockscontainer">
<div id="blockcontext">
<div class="block">
test content
</div>
<div class="block">
test content
</div>
<div class="block">
test content
</div>
<div class="block">
test content
</div>
<div class="block">
test content
</div>
<div class="block">
test content
</div>
<div class="block">
test content
</div>
<div class="block">
test content
</div>
<div class="block">
test content
</div>
<div class="block">
test content
</div>
<div class="block">
test content
</div>
<div class="block">
test content
</div>
<div class="block">
test content
</div>
<div class="block">
test content
</div>
<div class="block">
test content
</div>
<div class="block">
test content
</div>
<div class="block">
test content
</div>
<div class="block">
test content
</div>
<div class="block">
test content
</div>
<div class="block">
test content
</div>
<div class="block">
test content
</div>
<div class="block">
test content
</div>
<div class="block">
test content
</div>
<div class="block">
test content
</div>
<div class="block">
test content
</div>
<div class="block">
test content
</div>
<div class="block">
test content
</div>
<div class="block">
test content
</div>
<div class="block">
test content
</div>
<div class="block">
test content
</div>



</div>
</div>
</div>
<center>
<div id="footer">
content
</div>
</center>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Demo links are very helpful.  However, you should still put the relevant code in your question.  If the link disappears, the question could still be helpful to others.

Comment: first things first, if you're using jQuery, don't have any obtrusive JS. ie: body onload=""... is bad. Learn about $(document).ready();
And secondly, how about you describe what you're trying to accomplish because the code you have there is.... well... a lot of advanced code which jQuery will handle for you for what simple task I think you're trying to do.

Comment: if you look at the console, you get the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeName' of undefined"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you resize the window below a width of 1200 px, you call these lines:

```
$('.block').css("height", (winwidth - 30)/ 7.5 );
$('#blockscontainer').css("width", winwidth -20);
```

These are causing the issue you see, as they aren't reset to any kind of default when you increase the window size back about 1200px wide. This causes the page to look different because the width of #blockscontainer and the height of every .block element has changed.

Comment: this was basically what my issue was, I fixed it though by adding the necessary lines in time. Thankyou.